# tabactivity cannot work,but my code not mistake

Tags: android, android-tabhost

main.xml：

```
 <tabwidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <framelayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <linearlayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <listview android:id="@+id/list1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </linearlayout>
        <linearlayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <listview android:id="@+id/list2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </linearlayout>
    </framelayout>
```

```
public class TabbedListListActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

private static final String LIST1_TAB_TAG = "List1";
private static final String LIST2_TAB_TAG = "List2";

// The two views in our tabbed example
private ListView listView1;
private ListView listView2;

private TabHost tabHost;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);


    tabHost = getTabHost();
    // LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main, tabHost.getTabContentView(), true);


    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener((OnTabChangeListener) this);

    // setup list view 1
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

    // create some dummy strings to add to the list
    List<String> list1Strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1Strings.add("Item 1");
    list1Strings.add("Item 2");
    list1Strings.add("Item 3");
    list1Strings.add("Item 4");
    listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1Strings));

    // setup list view 2
    listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);

    // create some dummy strings to add to the list (make it empty initially)
    List<String> list2Strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    listView2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list2Strings));

    // add an onclicklistener to add an item from the first list to the second list
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = (String) listView1.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            if(item != null) {
                ((ArrayAdapter<String>) listView2.getAdapter()).add(item);
                Toast.makeText(TabbedListListActivity.this, item + " added to list 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    // add views to tab host
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST1_TAB_TAG).setIndicator(LIST1_TAB_TAG).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return listView1;
        }
    }));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST2_TAB_TAG).setIndicator(LIST2_TAB_TAG).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return listView2;
        }
    }));

}

/**
 * Implement logic here when a tab is selected
 */
public void onTabChanged(String tabName) {
    if(tabName.equals(LIST2_TAB_TAG)) {

    }
    else if(tabName.equals(LIST1_TAB_TAG)) {
        //do something
    }
}
 }
```

but this code not mistake but i canot  run this code,it give me
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.TabbedListListActivity/com.test.TabbedListListActivity.TabbedListListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class tabhost

i donot want o use inflate,every one can hlpe me ,i donot know where is midtake

Comment: you'd better put some more effort in asking your question if you want anyone to understand what you want... Paste code, specify what doesn't work, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the layout `<TabHost>` Tag. this is the right main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <tabwidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <framelayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <linearlayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <listview android:id="@+id/list1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </linearlayout>
        <linearlayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <listview android:id="@+id/list2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </linearlayout>
    </framelayout>
</TabHost>
```

For More Look out this [Article](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

Comment: thank you your reply,but your answer also cannot run.

Comment: i add <TabHost> Tag,but it is not appear in this article,i donot know why